# Local modification of built-in command via UpValue

Tags: function-construction, upvalues

I have a computationally intense function `f` that returns a matrix. Sometimes only the diagonal is needed, which is faster to compute, thus there's a syntax for f to return only the diagonal, say `f[...,Diagonal->True]`. I would like `Diagonal[f[...]]` to evaluate to `f[...,Diagonal->True]`.

Naive attempt at using `UpValue` fails

```
f[x_] := x.Transpose[x];
Diagonal[f[x_]] ^:= f[x, Diagonal->True];
```

because `f[...]` is evaluated first.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?
What would be the "Mathematica way" of handling this situation?

**Update:**

It appears that the requested behaviour might not be implementable in Mathematica.

Related approaches proposed so far:

- Hold argument to Diagonal: `Diagonal[Unevaluated@f[...]]` with UpValues `f /: Diagonal[f[x_]] := f[x, Diagonal -> True]`

  Works, but is more cumbersome than directly calling `f[..., Diagonal->True]` as one needs to remember using `Unevaluated` instead of an option to `f`
- Replace `Diagonal` by a convenience function `diagonal`, which works with `HoldAllComplete`

  Works, but is more cumbersome than directly calling `f[..., Diagonal->True]` as one needs to remember using another function `diagonal` instead of an option to `f`
- Define *only* UpValues for `f`, so it is only evaluated if it has a surrounding context

  Works, but requires modifying `$Post`, which is as undesirable as modifying the built-in `Diagonal`.

Comment: You can use `f /: Diagonal[f[x_]] := f[x, Diagonal -> True]` but it won't help because in standard evaluation sequence arguments of `Diagonal` will be evaluated before custom rules. (tutorial/Evaluation). Then you can use `Diagonal[Unevaluated@f[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]]` but is that handy?

Comment: @Kuba This would not be handy as it would be easier to call `f[..., Diagonal->True]` directly. Changing `Diagonal` via `Unprotect` to hold its argument is undesirable as well due to affecting other uses of `Diagonal`.

Comment: That is what I meant. I'd go with additional `diagonalF` but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no method to achieve the specific syntax and evaluation that you want that I would recommend in practice.  However for the sake of discussion a way to avoid the unwanted evaluation of the argument is to *only* define UpValues on `f`, which only evaluates `f[x]` when it has *some* surrounding expression.  To get evaluation of a bare input/output we need something like `$Post = Identity;`.  The order of definitions matters here as we need the `Diagonal` rule to trigger first.

```
ClearAll[f]

Diagonal[f[x_]] ^:= myFdiagonal[x]

h_[a___, f[x_], b___] ^:= h[a, x.Transpose[x], b]

$Post = Identity;
```

Now:

```
f[{{1}, {3}}]

Diagonal[ f[{{1}, {3}}] ]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {3, 9}}
>
> myFdiagonal[{{1}, {3}}]
> ```

`f[x]` should work inside any head that does not have `HoldAllComplete` and as long as a competing UpValue of a different function does not supersede it.

Comment: It seems even Mathematica itself does not do what I wanted: There is `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`, where `N[Integrate[...]]` appears to not directly translate to `NIntegrate`, but to first evaluate `Integrate` and then `N`. I have accepted your answer for stating that it is likely not possible to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think up-values are the way to go. I think you should write a new function, say `diag`, that has a special behavior for `f`, but works like `Diagonal` for any other args. Something like

```
f[x_] := x.Transpose[x]
f[x_, Diagonal -> True] := Diagonal[x]

SetAttributes[diag, HoldAllComplete]
diag[f[x_]] := f[x, Diagonal -> True]
diag[args___] := Diagonal[args]
```

Then with

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
```

you would get

```
f[m]
```

> `{{a^2 + b^2, a c + b d}, {a c + b d, c^2 + d^2}}`

```
diag[f[m]]
```

> `{a, d}`

but

```
diag[Inverse[m]]
```

> `{d/(-b c + a d), a/(-b c + a d)}`

I realize this is not so pretty a solution as you hoped for, but I believe it to be the least troublesome.

Comment: This is an option. However, if the user can remember to use `diag`, then he can remember to use `f[..., Diagonal -> True]`, which overall would be simpler. I was curious whether there is a way to transparently use the efficient solution (`f[..., Diagonal->True]`) even if the user forgets to explicitly request it and just uses `Diagonal[f[...]]`.

Comment: @mrupp. `diag` is purely a convenience function. Its only purpose is to make code entry easier. I thought that is what you are trying to accomplish.